# Resources for C++ programmer to learn JS

Tags: javascript, c++

I am proficient in C++, I dont know Java Script and want to learn JS, What should be the way/process for me? I know basic html, CSS.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Check out the **one and only** JavaScript Guide from MDC:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide

Besides that, forget everything you know about C++ it won't help you in any way. JavaScript is a completely different beast on its own.

It will take a lot of type to learn all the quirks of the language and the Browsers it runs in, if you want to do server side JavaScript check out Node.js, but be advised, learn **a lot** about JS before doing that.

Comment: Much better than the W3Schools link indeed.

Comment: MDC is a decent resource, but it's not the one and only, don't forget about the actual language specification which may be needed in a lot of cases.

Comment: @galambazs "Guide" - I don't think that the spec is a Guide.

Comment: > "Besides that, forget everything you know about C++ it won't help you in any way."­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ I disagree with that statement. Although the syntax is different in many ways, and C++ has some features that JS doesn't and visa-versa, most of the basic programming principles are the same.

Comment: I find the MDN tutorials overly verbose and cluttered by links.
It is actually the reason why I landed on this page to look for
an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

An answer that takes things in a different angle: Have you heard of [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki)?

Emscripten is basically a C/C++ to Javascript converter. It allows you to write code in C/C++, compile it, and then convert your compiled bitcode to Javascript.

Clearly, this isn't aimed at teaching a C++ programmer to write Javascript, so it isn't a direct answer to this question. But it does allow him to create Javascript code, in a round-about sort of way.

Of course, he could always try using it a learning tool, by writing some C++ code and studying the converted Javascript. It might be helpful in simple cases, although I suspect it wouldn't be ideal code to learn from.

Answer (score 1):

Good browser + a debugger plugin (both firefox and opera will suffice). Plus for the start its good to start on top of some good JS library: jQuery or Mootols (my favourites).

The hardest issue for me were the differences in the implementation. C++ compilers tend to break the standard, or implement just some parts of it, but the differences between javascript implementations are just insane.

If you are OK with C++, you will be able to code pretty easily, the syntax is similar, but everything is a lot simpler and dynamic.

Comment: *"Plus for the start its good to start on top of some good JS library: jQuery or Mootols (my favourites)."* Many people will disagree with that. jQuery for example is a layer over the DOM API, and won't help you to know the language. With regard to the *insane differences*, are you talking about implementations of the language, or of the DOM API?

Comment: @patrick When picking up any language it is always good to have some library that will allow you to code "useful" code without thinking a lot about the details. Sure, you need to fill the spaces sooner or later, but it helps a lot to have something to start on.

Comment: Well the question is regarding learning the language. I can perhaps see easing into the DOM API with a library like jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://codeavengers.com to learn JavaScript, it's the best and easiest way.

Answer (score -4):

There is no relation between c++ and javascript anyway, so being proficient in C++ does not help you learn javascript, altough it gives you heads up in getting accustomed to the writing code in javascript easily.

you can start here - http://homepage.ntlworld.com/kayseycarvey/

Comment: +1 I was just typing pretty much the same thing. In fact, going from C++ to JavaScript is potentially _harder_, since you might have to unlearn so many things that you took for granted...

Comment: No relation? I think it's much easier to learn a programming language when you already know one. Not to mention moving from something complex like C++ to something arguably simpler.

Comment: Actually you don't need to know anything about HTML to learn JavaScript. Whilst it is a general purpose language which just happens to be embedded into many browsers, it doesn't have to be and can be used for many other purposes.

Comment: 4 Upvotes? What are you guys doing? He links w3schools... worst place to learn JS **ever** -1 here.

Comment: @Ivo Wetzel - Well, it is a place to start off when you dont know anything.

Comment: Huh? Going from C++ to javascript is super simple and being proficient in C++ helps a ton.

Comment: w3schools is not a place to _start off when you dont know anything_. It'll make you come here on SO with lots of _stupid_ question.

Comment: Edited answer with a better link.

Comment: Sorry but that's just as bad as the other one. MDC is the only place to go.